# Chart JS date-hour AxesX

Tags: javascript, chart.js, scale

I would like to display somes data from JSON :

```
[{"heure":"08:00:00","date":"2017-08-09","payload":"1"}]
```

And I use Chart JS to build a chart :

```
for(var i in data) {
                heure.push("Heure " + data[i].heure);
                date.push(data[i].date);
                payload.push(data[i].payload);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: date,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: nomGraph,
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                        data: payload
                    }
                ]
            };
            var option = {
                scales: {
                    yAxes:[{
                        stacked:true
                    }],

                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        position: 'bottom',
                        time: {
                            tooltipFormat: "MM-DD-YYYY",
                        },
                    }],
                }
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata
            });
```

The problem is that I can not display a good scale on the X axis. I have 2017-08-09 or I would like 08-09-2017 thanks to this line:

```
tooltipFormat: "MM-DD-YYYY",
```

And the best would be to display Aug 09 10H with the time variable.

```
tooltipFormat: "MMM-DDD-HHHH",
```

But it does not work. Do you know why?

Comment: So your question is formatting date into Aug 09 10H

Comment: To begin i would like to understand why it didn't work with "MM-DD-YYYY". Because I guess "MMM-DDD-HHHH" will be more difficult, but yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chart js uses `moment.js` time formatters to format the tooltip string.
So I think the moment format tokens should work.
Read more about here.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

If the date is `2017-01-29 10:00:00 AM`,

`MMM-DD-HH` will equivalent to `Jan-29-10`

But I don't see any `HOUR` part in your date string. If you want the hours to be formatted you should input the date string in the following standard way with time data.

```
2013-02-04T22:44:30.652Z
```

There are several ISO standards available. You can choose one.
Read more about here.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/